# Save the transformation of Boolean Modifier Difference

Tags: modifiers

I currently have carved out a chunk in my mesh as shown in the picture using the boolean modifier.

The 'cutout' is the mesh I am using to carve out what I want from the 'bishop model' mesh.

[image]

How can I actually save the carved out mesh version so I can delete the 'cutout' mesh?

Is this possible?

Thanks.

Comment: Hello :). Just click *Apply* in the Boolean modifier. Then it will stay that way. And don't forget to backup your model first.

Comment: Thank you! Very helpful.

Answer (score 3):

Modifiers are what is called **non-destructive modifications**, they are meant for users to be able to do further editing before committing to a final irreversible transformation.

The idea is that you don't apply a modifier until you need to (if at all). It is not uncommon to never apply the modifiers. That way you can experiment or refine the settings, or further combine it with other modifiers, or change the order in which the modifiers act, without effecting the original object.

If you need to make the modification permanent then **Apply** the modifier. The transformations will now be part of the object and the modifier will disappear.

[image]

Comment: Related: [why do the boolean options disappear when the boolean modifier is applied?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/72611/why-do-the-boolean-options-disappear-when-the-boolean-modifier-is-applied/72613#72613)