# How to add an asymmetric mesh to a mesh with mirror modifier

Tags: mesh, mirror-modifier

I feel like this question must have been asked before, but i can't find anyone who asked it here

I am making a robot figure. The main body is a hexagon that was made symmetrical using the mirror modifier. Now i want to put a cube on the back right portion, but when i add the mesh, it mirrors it, and adds a mirrored mesh. I don't want to mirror the additional mesh, how can I choose which mesh gets mirrored and which do not?

This video seems to do something like it from 1:22 to 1:40

Comment: You need to keep your cube as a different object as long as you use a Mirror modifier for the body, when you'll apply the Mirror you'll be able to join the cube to the body (Ctrl J)

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/70068/is-there-any-way-to-disable-the-mirror-modifier-temporarily/ https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/30356/excluding-part-of-the-mesh-from-mirror-modifier

Comment: Add it as a new object in Object mode. It sounds as if you're adding it in Edit mode which will still be affected by the mirror modifier.

Comment: @JohnEason that makes sense, I'm going to try that